Match and replace based on conditions in R
Scrapped this massive (10M+ entries) Twitter dataset using academictwitteR, and as I am preparing to do some network analysis, I've come up against an issue whereby the dataset only identifies the used ID if a particular tweet is responding to another user (see mockup below). What I am trying to do across this dataset is a conditional replace whereby the user ID in the "in response to" column is replaced by the username.
Current database



ID_column
Username
In_response_to




ID12345
JohnA
NA


ID54321
JaneB
ID12345


ID51243
MarkE
ID54321



Desired outcome



ID_column
Username
In_response_to




ID12345
JohnA
NA


ID54321
JaneB
JohnA


ID51243
MarkE
JaneB



I have looked around extensively through SO and other forums for solutions, but I haven't managed to. Being relatively new to R, I am sure the answer will be staring me in the face...

library(dplyr)
data_df <- read.delim(file = textConnection('
ID12345 JohnA   NA
ID54321 JaneB   ID12345
ID51243 MarkE   ID54321
'), header = FALSE) |> setNames(c('ID_column', 'Username', 'In_response_to'))


lookup_list <- (data_df$Username) |> setNames(data_df$ID_column)

data_df |>
  mutate(In_response_to = recode(In_response_to, !!!lookup_list))


Thanks @br00t, this solution worked like magic - really appreciate the quick feedback!

Match the values in both columns twice. The matching order will do the trick.
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID_column     Username    In_response_to
ID12345     JohnA   NA
ID54321     JaneB   ID12345
ID51243     MarkE   ID54321",
header = TRUE)

i <- with(df1, match(ID_column, In_response_to)) |> na.omit()
j <- with(df1, match(In_response_to, ID_column)) |> na.omit()
df1$In_response_to[i] <- df1$Username[j]

df1
#>   ID_column Username In_response_to
#> 1   ID12345    JohnA           <NA>
#> 2   ID54321    JaneB          JohnA
#> 3   ID51243    MarkE          JaneB

Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0

Using data.table, you can solve your problem as follow:
library(data.table)

setDT(dt)[, In_response_to := Username[chmatch(In_response_to, ID_column)]]

   ID_column Username In_response_to
      <char>   <char>         <char>
1:   ID12345    JohnA           <NA>
2:   ID54321    JaneB          JohnA
3:   ID51243    MarkE          JaneB

